# Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'

Tags: android, flutter, android-app-bundle, flutter-android

Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Failed to read key locii from store "E:\Flutter-App\android\app\locii.jks": No key with alias 'locii' found in keysto
> re E:\Flutter-App\android\app\locii.jks

Comment: I think the stacktrace explains the problem _`"J:\Flutter-App\android\app\app\locii.jks' not found for signing config 'release'."`_
Have you created a _keystore_ file with the correct credentials?

Comment: yes, i did and the same thing was happened